# How can i refresh store redux toolkit after logout

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to reset all reducer in my store using redux toolkit after logout. But all my attempts were unsuccessful. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I usually follow this style. Keep an initial state for the store.

Revert back to that initial state when logout.

**Example:**

```js
const User = {
    name: "",
    username: ""
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "User",
  initialState: User,
  reducers: {
    setUserInfo: (state, { payload }) => {
        // Setting User Data
    },
    logoutUser: () => User
  }
});
```

or simply reload the page so that redux state gets empty.

Comment: This is only resetting a single state. What if we want to reset all the states in the store?